# Java: How do I install a package on Mac?

Tags: java, installation, package, scribe

I'm working on using scribe-java and ran into the following issue:

When I run in Terminal:

cd src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/
javac TwitterExample.java

I get the error:

package org.scribe.oauth does not exist

How do I install that package?

I'm using Eclipse if that matters.

Comment: My Google search took me here. Maybe this is not off-topic, Daniel, bmargulies, Rob, and JNK. (And taking into account up votes on the answer, I'd say this question's validity and usefulness to the community should be reassessed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should read the [Getting Started](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/getting-started) page.